# Customizing bootstrap variables with ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ng-bootstrap

I have inherited a project that uses Angular 7 & ng-bootstrap ^4.2.1.
I'd like to customize bootstrap variables (stuff like `$primary` etc).

**I'm perfectly aware that *IF* I am including bootstrap.scss I have to add my customizations before the @import '~bootstrap/bootstrap';`**

**Point is** when using `ng-bootstrap` I do **not** `@import` `bootstrap` at all! The `ng-bootstrap` library seem to do so on its own... which means I cannot put these variables anywhere.

## What I have tried

Looking at the `angular.json` file I noticed that some files are listed and I tried to add a new one containing my variables, however it does not matter whether I add it as first or last element nothing changes:

```
# angular.json
# ... a bunch of stuff
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/SomePath",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          <b>"src/bootstrap-vars.scss",    &lt;&lt;&lt; added this file overriding bootstrap variables</b>
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
          "src/styles.scss",
          <b>"src/bootstrap-vars.scss",    &lt;&lt;&lt; nothing seems to change placing it here</b>
        ],
```

<sub>For some reason SO wont let me use proper pre tags to properly bold lines...</sub>

Placing the variables inside the `src/styles.scss` file, as expected, does not produce any change.

My question is: how am I supposed to override the bootstrap variables when using bootstrap via ng-bootstrap?

I *guess* I should be doing something when defining the modules, for example I have this `SharedModule`:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {AgmAutocompleteComponent} from './features/agm-autocomplete.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HelperService} from './services/helper.service';
import {NgbDateParserFormatter, NgbDatepickerModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {MomentDateFormatter} from '../core/formatters/moment-date.formatter';
import {DatePickerComponent} from './features/date-picker.component';
import {UnexpectedErrorComponent} from "./features/unexpected-error.component"
import { SpinnerComponent } from './features/spinner.component';
import {WaitingComponent} from "./features/waiting.component"

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AgmAutocompleteComponent,
    DatePickerComponent,
    UnexpectedErrorComponent,
    SpinnerComponent,
    WaitingComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: environment.maps_api_key,
      libraries: ['places'],
    }),
    NgbDatepickerModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AgmAutocompleteComponent,
    StripeComponent,
    DatePickerComponent,
    UnexpectedErrorComponent,
    SpinnerComponent,
    WaitingComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    HelperService,
    {
      provide: NgbDateParserFormatter,
      useClass: MomentDateFormatter
    },
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

Maybe I should include something before the importing `NgbDateParserFormatter`/`NgbDatepickerModule`? But what/how?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Download the [bootstrap source files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/#source-files) and copy the folder bootstrap-4.5.0\scss in the root folder of your application. I copy all the folder and remove all the files else the directory scss

Simply add in your angular.json the bootstrap.scss

```
        "styles": [
          "bootstrap-4.5.0/scss/bootstrap.scss",
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
```

Each time you want, change the file _variables.scss from the folder bootstrap-4.5.0/scss

Comment: Why would i copy bootstrap when I **already** have it working? My question is how to override variables *with the current approach*. Moreover as you can see I already include bootstrap from `node_modules` and this does not work, why would using a local copy do anything different?

Comment: ng-bootstrap NOT required include bootstrap in node_modules (really you should avoid install bootstrap) only need the bootstrap.css. If you are using .css, just copy the bootstrap.min.css in a folder and include it in the angular.json. As you're using scss, you need copy the ".scss" in a folder and include it in the angular.json. Really I usually don't use ".scss", so my experience is very poor in this sense

Comment: AFAIK the project uses **also** standard bootstrap-js. So removing it is not an option. What I want is placing the scss in the correct loading order to override those variables. There must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should include source files of bootstrap, not the "dist" compiled version

```
"styles": [
   "src/bootstrap-vars.scss",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
]
```